# How to press ENTER in Nano on Ubuntu-touch via abd?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scripts, nano, adb

When I'm connected to Ubuntu Touch (bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu-Edition phone) via adb shell and I'm editing a shell script with Nano.

How can I press ENTER to save changes? Nano does not accept the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key via adb shell.

Answer (score -1):

You must use phablet-shell command rather than adb shell. It open a console with the device too. Then, you can put enter in nano and save files.